# How to merge DLLs into EXE in MinGW when linking

Tags: linker, mingw-w64, msys2, gnat, ghdl

I'm compiling [GHDL](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/) on my machine either with:

- [AdaCore GNAT GPL 2017](https://www.adacore.com/download)
  This is a standalone Ada compiler for Windows that produces a single executable;
  or with
- [MSYS2 / MinGW64](https://www.msys2.org/) (GCC + GNAT + CLANG, CLANG++, ...)
  This is the GCC compiler tool chain for Windows. It produces an executable that needs a handful of DLLs from MinGW in the installation directory.

Is it possible to add a linker flag to integrate the DLLs into the executable to reduce the number of shipped files?

What flags need to be set to merge the required dependencies into the executable?

---

In this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues/318), I listed all DLL dependencies for GHDL with LLVM backend:

- `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`
- `libstdc++-6.dll`
- `libwinpthread-1.dll`
- `zlib1.dll`

Answer (score 1):

There might be static libraries available for those things in the `/mingw32/lib` or `/mingw64/lib` directory if the MSYS2 developers built static versions of those libraries.  You can try passing the `-static` option to GCC during the link step and I think it will try to use the static versions if they are available.  I don't know of any way to merge DLLs into an executable, you have to link against static libraries instead.